# Get a file inside a specific package

Tags: java, class, package

I've a java package (package A) and I would retrieve a file contained into another package (package B).
For example, suppose that into package A I have a class named ClassA. The ClassA needs to access an xml file (i.e. a configuration file) contained into package B.

What is the procedure that I can use to access the configuration file from ClassA?

Thank you in advance. FA.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "...a file in a package..."?

Comment: By retrieve, you mean import the source or open the file as a resource?

Comment: packages contain classes and resources, not files. What file are you trying to get? an image? a .java file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream("/packageB/yourfile.ext");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `import` statement.

For example, to import class `Bar` from package `a.b.c.d` into your class in package `a.b.c`, you would write:

```
package a.b.c;

import a.b.c.d.Bar;

class Foo {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you cannot get the files of a package, by reflexion or otherwise.

Note that the classes of a package may be in many different folders (with different roots), in jars ..

But if you know your complete classpath, you can (complex task) search yourself in all these different locations...